# How to erase text in a image using GIMP?

Tags: images, gimp

I have this image, from [here](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/38172986@N05/7269541532/in/photostream):

[image]

I want to erase the text inside those circles. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with some careful usage of the Clone tool. But even then, you will have uneven results due to those circles being partially transparent and the fact that one circle overlaps another.